# Searching a website and returning found results

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, powerquery, data-retrieval

With Excel Power query its possible to pull data from a website provided its in a database/table format.

Many online databased are so large however that they implement a search function instead of showing the entire database which is fine but causes a barrier when trying to efficiently locate information for many keywords.

The database I wish to search is:

https://apps.who.int/food-additives-contaminants-jecfa-database/search.aspx

Is it possible to create a list of keywords/CAS numbers and search the database for each of these sequentially and return data found? This is similar to web scraping but with the added step of actually searching for the data beforehand.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with powerquery or xmlhttp requests or browser automation? And what are example CAS/keywords?

Comment: In many ways it's more just exploring what is achievable with excel and if possible power query. An example CAS number would be 546-93-0 for MAGNESIUM CARBONATE

Comment: It's an aspx page so an efficient way is to mimic the POST xhr request the page does to search the database and alter the `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearch:` param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally possible to acheive what you want.
First you analyze the page, specifically the input box and the submit button and find what's identify them. I use Chrome Development Tools for this. Just open the desired page and press F12.

In this case the input box is:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearch" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearch">
```

and the submit button is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch" value="Search" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch">
```

You can then use the ids to address the box with javascript:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearch');
inputBox.value = 'your search string';
```

And the equivalent for the submit button:

```
var searchButton = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch');
searchButton.click(); // Start the search
```

When the results are delivered you then need to analyze that page to figure out what javascript code is needed to extract the part of that page that you're interrested in. Or you can dump the complete page with:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Excel VBA example code for running javascript on a webpage here:

https://github.com/peakpeak-github/libEdge

Modify the code to suit your needs.

Comment: Why would they add an extra dependency and run javascript when they can run native methods? `Dim searchButton As Object: searchButton = .document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch')` for example though explicit typing would be preferable. Or is this on the assumption they would automate Edge and this is the way to do it? Where would they run this from? Do they need to build an app?

Comment: The idea is to explore how much I could automate an excel spreadsheet pulling data from searchable databases online.

Comment: Yes, and that is what my answer is about. Look at the VBA sample. You can modify that with the javascript lines I proposed to automate Excel.

Comment: @QHarr wrote: *"Why would they add an extra dependency and run javascript when they can run native methods?"* Well, you can run old IE with VBA natively or you can run a modern browser (Chrome (=Edge)) with libEdge. Runnable samples for VBA, C++ and C# are included.